# show server time using php and jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I was trying to show the date and time of server using php and jquery ajax. following are the jquery script to show datetime

```
<script type= "text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.1.min.js"> </script>
    <script type= "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
function update() {
  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
  url: 'datetime.php',
  timeout: 1000,
  success: function(data) {
      $("#timer").html(''); 
    window.setTimeout(update, 1000);
   },
  });
 }
});

</script>

<div id="timer"> </div>
```

following are php script for datetime.php

```
 <?php

  $msg = date('d/m/Y h:i:s');
  echo $msg;

 ?>
```

I don't what is going wrong. It's not showing output. Any help

Comment: $("#timer").html(''); 

i think this should be $("#timer").html(data);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have almost got it. Just update this line

```
$("#timer").html(data);
```

Usage:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function update() {
      $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'datetime.php',
       timeout: 1000,
       success: function(data) {
          $("#timer").html(data); 
          window.setTimeout(update, 1000);
       }
      });
     }
     update();

});
```

Answer (score 3):

That is because you are setting the contents of the timer div to empty.  You never do anything with the data returned.

Change this line:

```
$("#timer").html('');
```

to this:

```
$("#timer").html(data);
```

It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

add to your js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#timer").load("datetime.php");
    }, 1000);
});
```

datetime.php:

```
<?php
    $msg = date('d/m/Y h:i:s');
    echo $msg;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function update() {
      $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'datetime.php',
       timeout: 1000,
       success: function(data) {
          $("#timer").html(data); 
          window.setTimeout(update, 1000);
       },
      });
     }
     update();

});
```

if the datetime is displayed on page load then use like the above one
otherwise call the update function on Onclick event i.e  show datetime