# How to make PHP date and time update automatically

Tags: php

I have a script which displays the date and time.

How can I add something to make it update automatically instead of on page refresh.

Here is the script:

```
<?php
$hourdiff = 0; // Replace the 0 with your timezone difference (;
$site = date("l, d F Y g:i a",time() + ($hourdiff * 3600));
echo $site;
?>
```

Can anyone help. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

PHP is a server side language, and only ways you are going to send request to the server, are through redirection, navigation, refresh or through an ajax request.

So, You will need Javascript for that.

Here is a simple [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pLsgJ/1/)

```
setInterval(function() {
    var currentTime = new Date ( );    
    var currentHours = currentTime.getHours ( );   
    var currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes ( );   
    var currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds ( );
    currentMinutes = ( currentMinutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentMinutes;   
    currentSeconds = ( currentSeconds < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentSeconds;    
    var timeOfDay = ( currentHours < 12 ) ? "AM" : "PM";    
    currentHours = ( currentHours > 12 ) ? currentHours - 12 : currentHours;    
    currentHours = ( currentHours == 0 ) ? 12 : currentHours;    
    var currentTimeString = currentHours + ":" + currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds + " " + timeOfDay;
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = currentTimeString;
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can display current time using javascript.

Here is one introducary article about this: http://www.elated.com/articles/creating-a-javascript-clock/

Also posible duplicate: [show server time using php and jquery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889226/show-server-time-using-php-and-jquery-ajax)

Comment: javascript shows the client time. It might be different from the PHP server time. just a note